# What do the shield icons on custom question list pages specify?

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, icons, custom-question-lists

I was just browsing through the Questions pages on Meta Stack Exchange, and noticed all questions have a shield icon in front of them. It reminds me of the icon sometimes used in Stack Overflow for Teams:

[image]

They do not appear on the home page, and this problem seems exclusive to [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377778/4751173) and this site.

Comment: Same shield as teams (which are shown near a post to show that it's a team post)

Comment: Leaked in with a recent change for Teams that's currently being tested on MSE/MSO - dev is working on a fix.

Comment: Man, I hope they turn that off for teams when you're *looking at the team*, @Shog9.  I get why you'd want to see it when team posts are mixed in with public ones on SO, but right now my team is a column of shieldy woe.

Comment: I got bad news for ya, @Monica... That's actually how it's *supposed to* look. Apparently folks wanted that extra-in-your-face reminder of privacy.